# How to print text to next line in asp.net MVC Controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on asp.net MVC and writing code in controller. I want to print this text in two line like:

Dear Name

Your Order is.....Stores

**Controller.cs**

```
Body = "Dear " + fullname + "<br/> Your Order have been successfully Placed. Number of products placed are " + Quantity + " from given Store "
```

I have tries both \n and `<br>` tag but both are not working. Please can anyone guide me in this regard.

Comment: why couldn't you put the html in View and pass full name and quantity from controller as model?

Comment: Please don't add every tag you see that might be relevant. While you're typing the tag, information about the tag shows below (on desktop). Please read that information. If you're using ASP.NET Core, you can't be using ASP.NET MVC 3, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace br tag or \n with System.Environment.NewLine :

```cs
Body = "Dear " + fullname + Environment.NewLine + "Your Order have been successfully Placed. Number of products placed are " + Quantity + " from given Store "
```

If it doesn't work out your problem may be where or how you are printing, and not in the string itself. It would be better to provide a little more code.